# @TestVisible can not be used in Trigger?

Tags: trigger

I saw many examples of usage of @TestVisible attestation with a plain apex class.
I tried to use it in a trigger, but no luck because TriggerName.myTestVisibleAttribute fails saying TriggerName not recognizable.

Any reason why this should be so?

Comment: you cannot use annotations in a trigger. If you want to control context move code to a class

Answer (score 2):

The reason @TestVisible is not available in a trigger is that a trigger is not instantiable/constructable nor is it really like a static class.

For example, you can't do:

```
AccountTrigger aTrigger = new AccountTrigger();
```

Hence, any variables inside the trigger can't be @TestVisible-annotated as there is no way to reference the containing trigger from a testmethod.

You'll note that modern trigger patterns are typically only one line, referencing a trigger handler class. See, for example the [fflib library as showcased on TrailHead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_patterns_dsl/units/apex_patterns_dsl_learn_dl_principles):

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (
  after delete, after insert, after update, after undelete, before delete, before insert, before update) {

   // Creates Domain class instance and calls appropriate methods
   fflib_SObjectDomain.triggerHandler(Accounts.class);
}
```

Comment: I would say "modern trigger patterns are typically logic-less". That's the way Salesforce words its [best practice](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices#Logic-less_Triggers). Some handler patterns are one line, but many are not. The common theme is moving the logic elsewhere.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - right-o